“Software & Updates” not responding
May i ask why the app does not respond when clicking on "Software&Updates"，And please provide some solutions？
The following is using "software-properties-gtk" command to check for errors. I don't know if it's related to the problem I encountered：
    nbuntu@ubuntu:~$ software-properties-gtk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
        app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 209, in __init__
        self.init_ubuntu_pro()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1547, in init_ubuntu_pro
        self.ubuntu_pro_page = UbuntuProPage(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/UbuntuProPage.py", line 97, in __init__
        if distro.eol_esm is not None:
    AttributeError: 'DistroRelease' object has no attribute 'eol_esm'
    nbuntu@ubuntu:~$ 

OS：Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Virtual machine：Vmware16
